# Help solving the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{(\ln(x))^x}{x^{\ln (x)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(\ln(x))^x}{x^{\ln (x)}}$$

I really don't know what to do here, as soon as I try to manipulate the expression I end up with something worse..
Thanks!

Comment: When you write "$\ln^x(x)$", I assume that you mean
$$\big(\ln(x)\big)^x\quad?$$
If so, please don't do so in the future; it is incorrect notation. That convention only applies to trigonometric functions (and is the cause of more confusion than it's worth even in that context).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks!

Comment: It clearly goes to infinity as the top grows much faster than the bottom.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case but I need to prove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the limit of the logarithm first:

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln \frac{(\ln x)^x}{x^{\ln x}} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x \ln (\ln x) - (\ln x)^2 \right) = \lim_{x\to\infty} x \left( \ln (\ln x) -  \frac{ (\ln x)^2}{x} \right) = \infty (\infty - 0) = \infty
$$

Since $\ln$ is continuous and injective, the original limit is also $\infty$.

Comment: So basically, everytime I have an indetermination of the form inf-inf I should try to find a common term, right?

Comment: @milo It really depends. I don't think there is a general rule for all $\infty - \infty$ situations. My tip is that if you see $f(x)^{g(x)}$, take the logarithm and try to simplify.

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln^xx}{x^{\ln x}}=\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{x\ln\ln x-\ln^2x}=\infty$$
because by l'Hopital's rule
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\ln x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\rightarrow \infty$$